# Prove: if every monotonic subsequence of $x_n$ converges to $x$ then $x_n$ converges to $x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove: if every monotonic subsequence of $x_n$ converges to $x$ then $x_n$ converges to $x$

At first, it looked to me like an easy to solve question, but actually I'm kinda stuck.
Can you give me a direction?

thanks!

Comment: If $(x_n)$ does not converge to $x$, it has a subsequence that is bounded away from $x$.  This subsequence has a further, monotone subsequence (see the Lemma [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)).

Comment: Dear @Peter, the statement is more strong than you think. He said that every monotonic subsequence converges. In your case the monotone subsequence: 1,2,3,4,... does no converge

Comment: @DavidMitra, please write your comment as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $(x_n)$ does not converge to $x$, it has a subsequence that is bounded away from x. This subsequence has a further, monotone subsequence (see the Lemma [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)).